# How to reverse the single quotes and double quotes in javascript to make it a valid json for parsing

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, javascript-objects

I have an API response coming in like this:

```
[{'name': 'men', 'slug': 'men'}, {'name': 'women', 'slug': 'women'}]
```

When I stringify it it becomes

```
const raw = JSON.stringify(resp)
"[{'name': 'men', 'slug': 'men'}, {'name': 'women', 'slug': 'women'}]"
```

I want it in this format,

```
'[{"name": "men", "slug": "men"}, {"name": "women", "slug": "women"}]'
```

I tried with replaceAll, and replace functions, but I am not able to convert it properly, can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: This all seems extremely weird to me. First of all, why does an API send wannabe JSON instead of the real thing? Plus, if your API response is text, why would you stringify it? And if it isn't text, why on earth would you want to turn it into text? This is almost certainly an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/) so please provide more details and context. It also has absolutely zero to do with React, which is a frontend library not even remotely concerned with parsing JSON or APIs.

Comment: I want to map it and get the name and slug like this, `obj.map((name, slug)=> (
  console.log(name.name)
))`. only then, I can proceed with the work.

Comment: That's not enough. What API is this? Is it your own? Why is it sending broken JSON? And if you want to use properties of the original data structure, why would you use `stringify`?

Comment: Yes, it is actually a list of tags, its name and slug sending from the backend. this is how it is received at the frontend `tag: "[{'name': 'shoe', 'slug': 'shoe'}, {'name': 'sneaker', 'slug': 'sneaker'}, {'name': 'sports', 'slug': 'sports'}]"`. and when I map the main objects and get `obj.tag` it becomes like `[{'name': 'men', 'slug': 'men'}, {'name': 'women', 'slug': 'women'}]`

Comment: Again, who wrote this API, and why is it putting "single-quote JSON" as string into actual JSON? (at least that's what it looks like) If you cannot fix the broken API code, you need to show your attempt at turning the text into actual JSON and parsing it.

Comment: The thing is it is working well while using rest api, but since we are about to change it to graphql, this problem pops up.

Comment: If there's no way to fix this, here's how to do it: https://jsfiddle.net/pt74h1j5/

Answer (score 2):

I suggest fix the API to return valid JSON.

Other solitions:

1. Fast but dangerous: use `eval()` function, ie.:

   ```
    eval('var data = ' + resp)
    const raw = JSON.stringify(data)
   ```
2. Safer but tedious: write own parser of this almost-JSON API response.

Comment: OP's replace approach is better than each of those alternatives.

Comment: @ChrisG I have to disagree. Without any knowledge about the source of this data, you have to assume that some values may contain double quotes (e.g., `[{'onClick': 'alert("Hello")'}]`) or escaped quotation marks (e.g., `[{'name': 'O\'Riley'}]`). Simple string replacement will break this.

Comment: @r3mainer Obviously true in theory, however imo it's still preferable and way easier to do multiple replace operations to prevent errors like that. Plus answerer is still stringifying a string, so I'll stick to my downvote for now.